# Gmail Api Resumable attachment. (Rest)

Tags: rest, attachment, gmail-api

Does anyone has any example of Gmail Api resumable uploading(for attachments). I succeeded using the main upload for attachments up to 5 MB but I would like to send attachments over 30 MB.I cant use gmail SDK to everything needs to be in Rest Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail API [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable)

The steps for using resumable upload include:

**Step 1: Start a resumable session**

To initiate a resumable upload, make a POST or PUT request to the method's /upload URI and add the query parameter uploadType=resumable, for example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=resumable
```

For this initiating request, the body is either empty or it contains the metadata only; you'll transfer the actual contents of the file you want to upload in subsequent requests.

**Step 2: Save the resumable session URI**

If the session initiation request succeeds, the API server responds with a 200 OK HTTP status code. In addition, it provides a Location header that specifies your resumable session URI. The Location header, shown in the example below, includes an upload_id query parameter portion that gives the unique upload ID to use for this session.

Example: Resumable session initiation response

Here is the response to the request in Step 1:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=xa298sd_sdlkj2
Content-Length: 0
```

**Step 3: Upload the file**

To upload the file, send a PUT request to the upload URI that you obtained in the previous step. The format of the upload request is:

```
PUT session_uri
```

Full code implementation sample is in the docs.

Comment: In step 1 when i make a Post on i get an error  `[ "error": {
      "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badContent",
                "message": "Media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822]"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822]"
    }']`  the request body is empty and the Authorization header is Bearer my_ath_token. @noogui

Comment: the file you're uploading is not supported, pretty clear to me

Comment: the file should be inside Raw?I mean the base64 encoded rfc822 should be inside Raw? When i try to send files more than 5 MB the encoded file inside Raw becomes huge. Can u give me and example of the format of the attachment before base64 encode? @noogui

Answer (score 0):

you need upload PUT method

but not binary body, only use multipart form body